# If I inner join in a linq-to-sql, what kind of a return type do I get?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Say I have a Article object, and a Category object.

The article object has a CategoryID property.

With linq-to-sql, how would I get list of articles and its associated category?

What will the return type be?

Answer (score 2):

it will return an "Anonymous Type" that is of the shape of what you define in your select.

here is a link to more on this.
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/15/new-orcas-language-feature-anonymous-types.aspx?CommentPosted=true